# I have a hashtable of nodes. How to print each individual values of each node in the hashtable?

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm getting a Segmentation Fault. This is really basic but I don't know how.

From my understanding this is what I'm doing:

- I made a struct named node. A node has two values: string WORD and pointer NEXT.
- I made a table which is an array of two nodes.
- node1 has value WORD equal "Goal". node2 has value WORD equal "Jonas".
- I tried to print the value WORD of both nodes.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main(void)
  {
      typedef struct node
      {
          char word[50];
          struct node *next;
      } node;

      node *table[2];

      strcpy(table[0]->word, "Goal");
      strcpy(table[1]->word, "Jonas");

      printf("%s\n", table[0]->word);
      printf("%s\n", table[1]->word);

  }
  ```

In my mind this is what I wanted to do:

TABLE:

```
________________
|        |      |
| "Goal" | NULL | -> this is node1
|________|______|
|        |      |
|"Jonas" | NULL | -> this is node2
|________|______|
```

Comment: You have an array of pointers. But *where do the pointers actually point?*

Comment: You have an array of pointers to nodes, but none of the elements are initialized to point to anything before you use them.

Comment: I don't need them to point to anything now. I did table[0]->next=NULL; but still got SegFault.

Comment: But that dereferences the pointer `table[0]`! You can't dereference a pointer unless it points to something valid. Perhaps you should spend a little more time reading books or tutorials about pointers?

Comment: Ohhh okay. I think it clicked now! I wanted to do that table[i] = malloc! Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes I will read them!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways I to make it right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
    {
        char word[50];
        struct node *next;
    } node;

    node table[2];

    strcpy(table[0].word, "Goal");
    strcpy(table[1].word, "Jonas");

    printf("%s\n", table[0].word);
    printf("%s\n", table[1].word);
}
```

Or using malloc():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
    {
        char word[50];
        struct node *next;
    } node;

    node *table[2];

    table[0] = malloc(sizeof *table[0]);
    table[1] = malloc(sizeof *table[0]);

    table[0]->next = NULL;
    table[1]->next = NULL;


    strcpy(table[0]->word, "Goal");
    strcpy(table[1]->word, "Jonas");

    printf("%s\n", table[0]->word);
    printf("%s\n", table[1]->word);

    free(table[0]);
    free(table[1]);
}
```